# How can i tell PHP which form is submitted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Is there a way to tell PHP which form has been submitted?

Form 1

```
<form id="factory" action="bullets.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Kopen">
</form>
```

And form 2

```
<form id="localFactory" action="bullets.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Kopen">
</form>
```

These forms are on one page.

My javascript code:

```
    var url;

    $('form').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        url = $(this).attr('action');

        location.hash = url;

        $.ajax ({
            url: url,
            method: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize()
        }).done(function (html) {
            $('#content').html(html);
        });
    });
```

If i got an input i get a $_POST variable.

So i need to know which of the above forms has been submitted?

Thanks..

Comment: Did you try using different names for the submit buttons?

Comment: @kingkero yes i did, i dont get a post variable back..

Comment: Add hidden field to each form with a 'formID' name and set unique value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work:

```
var url;

$('form').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    url = $(this).attr('action');

    location.hash = url;
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    data += "&formId=" + encodeURIComponent($(this).attr('id')); // if you have data in the form.
    // do this if you don`t have data in the form:
    // data = {formId: $(this).attr('id')};

    $.ajax ({
        url: url,
        method: 'POST',
        data: data
    }).done(function (html) {
        $('#content').html(html);
    });
});
```

You can then get the forms Id from `$_POST['formId']`

Answer (score 1):

Create a submit button with a name:

```
<form id="factory" action="bullets.php" method="post">
    <button type="submit" value="factory" name="submit">Kopen</button>
</form>
```

This value is now posted:

```
if (!empty($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'factory') { 

}
```

Comment: Nope, print_r($_POST) is empty

Comment: I didn't notice you also had a piece of javascript submitting the form via ajax. See lshas's answer.

Answer (score 0):

By namespacing the input fields, you can easily identify which fields are from which form, and by extension which form was submitted.

```
<form id="factory" action="bullets.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="form_1[my_input]">
    <input type="submit" value="Kopen">
</form>

<form id="localFactory" action="bullets.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="form_2[my_input]">
    <input type="submit" value="Kopen">
</form>
```

Then it is as simple as:

```
if (isset($_POST['form_1'])) { 
    // This post variable is an array of each field.
}
```

Comment: Where do the random textfields come from? His button is called: "Kopen" which means "buy" in dutch which you might not know, so this could be 2 forms with just buttons like he shows in his example.

Comment: @Loko I didn't know that, but I stand by this solution, as the namespace can be applied to the submit button as a normal practice.  It covers cases where a form has multiple submit buttons.  Then, if you have multiple forms with multiple submit buttons each, things start getting complicated without some form of grouping.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an html only solution, you could add a hidden input with the form id:

```
<form id="factory" action="bullets.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="factory" name="formId"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Kopen">
</form>
```

And then test it with:

```
if (isset($_POST['formId']) && $_POST['formId'] == 'factory') { 
   //Do what you want here
}
```